# VueJS not building all images

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

Im facing an issue with building VueJS app, so I have some images stored in src/assets/image/ and im using mongodb as database which im storing there the path of images for example. '../../../src/assets/image/deluxe.png', locally it works fine, but after building project and I go live the images are not appearing, and I noticed that VueJS is not building those images whose path comes from the database. Here is Card component which im sending all props:
`<Card v-for="listProduct in productList" :key="listProduct.id" :card-data="listProduct"/>`, and in Card.vue here is how img tag looks like: `<img :src="cardData.imageField" class="card-image w-full h-full transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-110" />`. Does anyone has any idea why those images are not building and do you have any solution about that?

I was expecting that all images in src/assets/image will be builded afer running the command `npm run build`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.